# How do I get an instance of Angular router without injecting it?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, injectable

Usually I'd go like this in my component.

```js
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

@Component({ ... })
export class CompyTheComponent {
  constructor(private router: Router) { 
    console.log(router.url);
  }
}
```

What if I want to obtain a reference of it **without** injecting it? I've tried to create it but died on all the parameters I couldn't figure out. Ans since it's not the usual (nor recommended) way to approach it, there's not much googlearch on it.

```js
let routy : Router = new Router(...);
```

Comment: Why don't you want to inject it?

Comment: @Zircon I'm curious if it **can** be done. I had once a static set up of helping methods and that's why the question arose. I do admit it's unusual approach. The question is rather academical than pragmatic.

Comment: Router is a complex provider that will require instantiate its all dependencies manually, too. Its dependencies include core stuff like compiler and injector, you will end up recreating the entire Angular app from scratch by hand. Possible in theory, a waste of time in practice.

Comment: The router is set up as a service that is meant to be injected. I don't think that it is meant to be used except in the context of a service. Plus the router service manages the location bar, so it is very important that there is only ever one instance of it.

Comment: what do you want to do with the router? you can get the `router` from the `moduleInjector` using `.get` method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a file called `injector.ts` with the following code:

```
import { Injector } from "@angular/core";

let appInjectorRef: Injector;

export function appInjector (injector?: Injector): Injector {
    if (!injector) {
        return appInjectorRef;
    }
    appInjectorRef = injector;
    return appInjectorRef;
}
```

Then in your `main.ts`:

```
bootstrap([...]).then((appRef: { injector: Injector }) => appInjector(appRef.injector))
  .catch((err: Error) => console.error(err));
```

Then you can use it as:

```
const router: Router = appInjector().get(Router);
```

In any case, I'd recommend dependency injection over this.

Comment: This actually is injection, just not constructor injection, and a really roundabout way of doing it. Better to just do it the "normal" way.

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek What if you're just building a small library that needs access to a router instance? This approach has the benefit that you can use it inside of a function - you don't need to build an entire class just so you can have a constructor in which you can inject the router.

Answer (score 1):

As of Angular 14, you can also use the `inject()` function.

```
import { inject } from "@angular/core"
import { Router } from "@angular/router"

const router = inject(Router)
```